Find a conformal map from $\{0 < \Im z < 1\}$ to $\{\max\{|z-1|,|z+1|\}< \sqrt{2}\}$
Find a conformal/biholomorphic map from $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: 0 < \Im z < 1\}$ to $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\max\{|z-1|,|z+1|\}< \sqrt{2}\}$ (explicitly).
Such a map obviously exist, due to Riemann mapping theorem, but I don't really know how to progress.
I figure the two lines of the stripes "go" to the respective circles, but that's about it.
Also I think the map can't be a restriction of a Cayley Mapping because else my other "observation" couldn't hold, which would be surprising.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1268957/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/398629/42969.

Try the other way: Starting from the lens shape between the two circles, observe that we have right angles at $-i$ and $i$. So do $z\mapsto z+i$ to bring one to the origin, then $z\mapsto 1/z$ to bring that to infinity. Now you have quadrant with a right angle at $1/(2i)$, ...

Thank you very much! So in general, for "weird" shapes like that you look for right angles and stuff?

@Batixx Yes. Then you can eliminate an angle by squaring (or other power, depending on the angle). Note however that the other end of your problem has a cusp (an angle of zero), which requires a different trick
